# Server not send messages via Express.js using whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, whatsapp

When I confirm the QR code with my phone, "READY" is printed on my console, but when I send a JSON request to the "/sendmessage" part, I get a "404" error. Likewise, I get "404" in "/getqr".
I could not understand exactly where I made a mistake, it was written in the whatsapp-web.js document that I should use "LocalAuth". Since I use multiple devices, I saw how to do it this way from the document, but I could not find a solution.
I'm very new to Express.js, I'm trying to learn, I'd be glad if you could help.

```
const express = require('express');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal')
require('dotenv').config();


const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';
let sessionCfg;
if (fs.existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) {
  sessionCfg = require(SESSION_FILE_PATH);
}

const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
    clientId: "client-one"
  }),
  puppeteer: {
    headless: false,
  }
});

client.initialize();

client.on('qr', qr => {
  console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
  qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
  app.get('/getqr', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ qr });
  });
});

client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
  console.log('WHATSAPP WEB => Authenticated');
});

client.on('auth_failure', msg => {
  console.error('AUTHENTICATION FAILURE', msg);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('READY');
});



const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));


app.post('/sendmessage', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { number, message } = req.body; // Get the body
    const msg = await client.sendMessage(`${number}@c.us`, message); // Send the message
    res.send({ msg }); // Send the response
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError.NotFound());
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send({
    status: err.status || 500,
    message: err.message,
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(` @ http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

[image][image]

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : When I send a request with GET it works, but when I send it with POST I get a 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, I was sending the request as GET instead of POST :(